# Notepad++ Insert text in between lines

Tags: notepad++

In Note pad, I have data like this:

```
(0, 0, 0, UK, ,NULL, NULL),
(0, 0, 0, SE, ,NULL, NULL),
(0, 0, 0, DE, ,NULL, NULL), //And 100 more lines
```

I need to insert the country name after the country code, which are stored on every line like this:

```
United Kingdom,
Sweden,
Germany,
```

So the end result is:

```
(0, 0, 0, UK, United Kingdom, NULL, NULL),
(0, 0, 0, SE, Sweden, NULL, NULL),
(0, 0, 0, DE, Germany, NULL, NULL), //And 100 more lines
```

I tried `Alt+Shift+Down Arrow` and then `paste`, but that would not work. Any method of doing this?

Comment: Why simply Find and Replace All won't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy all country names with <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> pressed (column selection mode), and simply paste it after the "UK,".

Comment: +1, but you have to select the comma before NULL before pasting if you don't want to have two commas.